# Should adobe-air and air tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Since [adobe-air](/questions/tagged/adobe-air) and [air](/questions/tagged/air) are the same thing, shouldn't the two be merged? Then going on the basis of other adobe products the final tag should be [air](/questions/tagged/air) so it's like [flex](/questions/tagged/flex) and [actionscript](/questions/tagged/actionscript).

Answer (score 3):

I personally think it should be merged to [adobe-air](/questions/tagged/adobe-air).

Comment: So, to be consistent, it should be adobe-flash and adobe-flex?

Comment: @Nebula I think `flash` is in common use so the `adobe-` prefix isn't necessary, but I think it should probably be `adobe-flex` not `flex`.

Comment: adobe-flex is already a synonym.